# stieltjes integration in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, numerical-integration

I want to build an implicit integration calculator with respect to Stieltjes integration means I integrate in respect to some measure (not necessarily Lebesgue) and to get a "function object" in which I can substitute, add or substructure another function object. I thought using SciPy but the integration there is not stieltjes integration.

Do anybody know a library that does it ? If not: how can I implement implicit integration which returns function **object**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is probably achievable with [Sympy](http://sympy.org) or some other symbolic computation system such as [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net). I don't know if Sympy already has an implementation of Stieltjes integrals, but using the stuff already available you should be able to do it.

Comment: does maxima can be used from python?

Comment: @DanisFischer Well, it is possible, but I think there is nothing to be gained by it. Maxima does not have built-in functions for Stieltjes integrals so you would have to invent some machinery of your own. You would have to do the same thing with Sympy too, but if you do it with Maxima, there is going to be an additional layer of glue code which is really unnecessary. My advice is to do it with Sympy. There is a [Sympy user forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sympy) where you can post a question.

Answer (score 0):

What about this symbolic `sympy` solution for the Stiltjes integral of

```
integral sin(x) d(x^2)
```

```py
sympy.init_session()
f = sin(x)
g = x**2
I = integrate(f*g.diff(), x)
```

This gives me the indefinite integral:

```
-2⋅x⋅cos(x) + 2⋅sin(x)
```

If you want to have this integral between e.g. 0 and `pi`, you can get it like:

```py
I.subs({x: pi}) - I.subs({x: 0})
```

Or if you want explicitly import all the things you need, and use a function to calculate the result, here's the code:

```py
from sympy import integrate, symbols, sin, pi
x = symbols('x')


def stiltjes(f, g, a, b):
    I = integrate(f*g.diff(), x)
    return I.subs({x: b}) - I.subs({x: a})


result = stiltjes(sin(x), x**2, 0, pi)
```